# Execution of TF1.X code with TF2.2 causes errors

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

How can I fix the following error in Tensorflow 2.2? I prefer to convert the code to something compatible to work with TF2.2 not to use the compact version if possible.

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'
```

---

```
[3306:3298 0:1022] 01:57:24 Tue Dec 29 [mona@goku:pts/0 +1] ~/research/code/DJ-RN/pointnet
$ python train.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 260, in <module>
    train()
  File "train.py", line 96, in train
    pointclouds_pl, labels_pl = MODEL.placeholder_inputs(BATCH_SIZE, NUM_POINT)
  File "/home/mona/research/code/DJ-RN/pointnet/models/pointnet_cls.py", line 13, in placeholder_inputs
    pointclouds_pl = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_point, 3))
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'
```

also

```
[3306:3298 0:1023] 01:57:31 Tue Dec 29 [mona@goku:pts/0 +1] ~/research/code/DJ-RN/pointnet
$ python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 07:30:14) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.__version__
'2.2.0'
>>> quit()
12149/31772MB
[3306:3298 0:1024] 01:59:05 Tue Dec 29 [mona@goku:pts/0 +1] ~/research/code/DJ-RN/pointnet
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
12149/31772MB

$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

As you see below, placeholder is not a method:

```
>>> tf.compat.v1.summary.
tf.compat.v1.summary.Event(                    tf.compat.v1.summary.get_summary_description(
tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter(               tf.compat.v1.summary.histogram(
tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriterCache(          tf.compat.v1.summary.image(
tf.compat.v1.summary.SessionLog(               tf.compat.v1.summary.initialize(
tf.compat.v1.summary.Summary(                  tf.compat.v1.summary.merge(
tf.compat.v1.summary.SummaryDescription(       tf.compat.v1.summary.merge_all(
tf.compat.v1.summary.TaggedRunMetadata(        tf.compat.v1.summary.scalar(
tf.compat.v1.summary.all_v2_summary_ops(       tf.compat.v1.summary.tensor_summary(
tf.compat.v1.summary.audio(                    tf.compat.v1.summary.text(
```

I also have tried the following for import as mentioned in forums and git issues however it doesn't work (it is also in the official tensorflow documentation for code migration: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate):

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

This is the error I get:

```
$ python train.py 
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/compat/v2_compat.py:96: disable_resource_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variable_scope) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
non-resource variables are not supported in the long term
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 260, in <module>
    train()
  File "train.py", line 96, in train
    pointclouds_pl, labels_pl = MODEL.placeholder_inputs(BATCH_SIZE, NUM_POINT)
  File "/home/mona/research/code/DJ-RN/pointnet/models/pointnet_cls.py", line 15, in placeholder_inputs
    pointclouds_pl = tf.compact.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_point, 3))
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v1' has no attribute 'compact'
```

The code resides in this repo: `https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet/issues/265`

Comment: [Migration](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) process can be both easy or hard depends on model you are using, anyway it will takes some time to do it. Using `compat` is cheap, not much time-consumable. The only thing do not mix using `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf` and other `compat`s - if you are going to use TF1.x-style, use it everywhere. Also update get latest code from repo - seems like they [fixed typo](https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet/blob/539db60eb63335ae00fe0da0c8e38c791c764d2b/models/pointnet_cls.py#L13).

Comment: The version I have installed is the version compatible with my CUDA.

Comment: Yeah it can be. I meant code from github repo you are using. `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf` `tf.disable_v2_behavior()` should work just fine. There was an issue with typo/mixed compat, now seems fixed.

Comment: Please check the OP. I have used `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf tf.disable_v2_behavior()` and that throws an error @AlexK.

Comment: I have checked OP and repo you are using. You have a typo: not `compact` but `compat`. You can replace all calls not supported by TF2 with tf.compat.v1 OR `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf` in all files around project. This will not port your code to TF2 but will make it work in compatibility mode. Just pick one option, do not mix them.

Comment: Could it be that its a typo? compact could be compat

Comment: import tensorflow.compact.v1 as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compact'
 @Dr.Snoopy

Comment: yes, I am pointing out that compact should be compat, look at the typo between compact and compat

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy compat here most probably means compatibility I'd guess

Comment: Yes, that is why the module is called tensorflow.compat.v1, you should fix it in your pointnet script

Comment: gotcha. Thanks a lot for bringing that to my attention

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'

Comment: It works for me if I do: import tensorflow then import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf , and then tf.placeholder is there.

Comment: The person who wrote the answer has deleted their answer. I am not sure how to make that accepted! @Dr.Snoopy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

instead of

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

and then use it like:

```
tf.placeholder()
```

e.g.,

```
pointclouds_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, point_num, 3))
```